# jquery selector: property AND traversing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select a div with jquery which is checked only if it's parent is visible. How must the selector look like? This doesn't work:

```
$(this)[is=":checked"][parent=".visible"]
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: 
earlier this worked
`$(this).is(":checked")`
but I need to filter this further with the condition the parent is of class _visible_.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you're asking about an element with the *class* `visible` (you're using a class selector, `.visible`, in your question) or one that *is* visible (jQuery's `:visible` pseudo-selector). I'll assume the latter.

The selector would be: `:visible :checked` (for a `:checked` element anywhere within a `:visible` element) or `:visible > :checked` (for a `:checked` element that's the direct child of a `:visible` element).

If you meant the class `visible` instead, change `:visible` to `.visible` in the above.